# Access TFS work Items using azure worker role

Tags: c#, azure, tfs

I have a worker role in azure which uses a service account 'myservice' and password is stored in keyvault. Now I have access TFS work Items using TFS APIs.

For testing, I have passed my credentials as

```
    NetworkCredential networkCred = new NetworkCredential("myusername","mypassword");
    ICredentials cred = (ICredentials)networkCred;
    TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(tfsUri, cred);
```

But now I have to pass the service account name 'myservice' and its password.
How do I use service account to access the TFS work Items?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to consume TFS API using OData Services as explained below：
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/briankel/2011/10/26/odata-service-for-team-foundation-server-2010-v1/

Have a read of this [link](https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/), then follow the instructions from "Team Foundation Service authentication:" to set up your account/profile to access the Api.

You can then access the resources via the web Api.